# Tkinter (python 2.7) | determine whether its tk instance or toplevel instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit, toplevel

**Question**

```
root1 = tk.Tk()
root2 = tk.Toplevel()
```

How can I determine from `root1` and `root2` whether the instance is tk or toplevel?

**My situation (for more context)**

I open two Tkinter (instance) window using the same `myCustomGUI` code.

```
root = tk.Tk()
mainGUI = myCustomGUI(root)
mainGUI.handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

root2 = tk.Toplevel()
secondGUI = myCustomGUI(root2)
secondGUI.handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

In the `myCustomGUI` class, I created a `on_closing()` function which runs when the user closes the window (`root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)`).

In the said function `on_closing()` I want to have something like this:

```
def on_closing(self):
    if self.root is tk:
        self.root.quit()
        exit() # exit the whole program OR run some custom exit function
    else: # meaning self.root is Toplevel
        pass
    self.root.destroy()
```

In other words, when the instance is Toplevel then only destroy it and when the instance is the main window, then quit tkinter and exit the whole program.

**Additional notes (NOT relevant to the question)**

The purpose of opening two windows with the identical interface is to print debug info in one window and print important info in the other window, thus the interface is the same.

The purpose I created a `on_closing()` function is because I have to remove the handler from `logger`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to ask tkinter what class the widget is -- not the python class but rather the internal tk class. For the root window it will be `Tk`, and for a toplevel it will be `Toplevel` (unless you've explicitly changed it, which would be highly unusual).

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyTop(tk.Toplevel):
    pass

root = tk.Tk()
top = tk.Toplevel(root)
mytop = MyTop(root)

assert(root.winfo_class() == "Tk")
assert(top.winfo_class() == "Toplevel")
assert(mytop.winfo_class() == "Toplevel")
```